# How to check if logstash receiving/parsing data from suricata to elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4, logstash-configuration

Trying to configure suricata v2.0.8 with ElasticSearch(v1.5.2)-Logstash(v1.4.2)-Kibana(v4.0.2) on Mac OS X 10.10.3 Yosemite.

***suricata.yaml:***

```
# Extensible Event Format (nicknamed EVE) event log in JSON format
  - eve-log:
      enabled: yes
      type: file #file|syslog|unix_dgram|unix_stream
      filename: eve.json
      # the following are valid when type: syslog above
      #identity: "suricata"
      #facility: local5
      #level: Info ## possible levels: Emergency, Alert, Critical,
                   ## Error, Warning, Notice, Info, Debug
      types:
        - alert
        - http:
            extended: yes     # enable this for extended logging information
            # custom allows additional http fields to be included in eve-log
            # the example below adds three additional fields when uncommented
            #custom: [Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Authorization]
        - dns
        - tls:
            extended: yes     # enable this for extended logging information
        - files:
            force-magic: yes   # force logging magic on all logged files
            force-md5: yes     # force logging of md5 checksums
        #- drop
        - ssh
        #- smtp
        #- flow
```

***logstash.conf:***

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["/var/log/suricata/eve.json"]
    sincedb_path => ["/var/lib/logstash/"]
    codec =>   json
    type => "SuricataIDPS"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }

}

filter {
  if [type] == "SuricataIDPS" {
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
    }
    ruby {
      code => "if event['event_type'] == 'fileinfo'; event['fileinfo']['type']=event['fileinfo']['magic'].to_s.split(',')[0]; end;"
    }
  }

  if [src_ip]  {
    geoip {
      source => "src_ip"
      target => "geoip"
      #database => "/usr/local/opt/logstash/libexec/vendor/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat"
      add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
      add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
    }
    mutate {
      convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float" ]
    }
    if ![geoip.ip] {
      if [dest_ip]  {
        geoip {
          source => "dest_ip"
          target => "geoip"
          #database => "/usr/local/opt/logstash/libexec/vendor/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat"
          add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
          add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
        }
        mutate {
          convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
    #protocol => http
  }
}
```

Suricata logs all events successfully into ***eve.json***. When I open kibana in browser, I see no dashboards or any information from suricata... So I assume either logstash doesn't read the data from eve.json or doesn't parse the data to elasticsearch (or both)... Are there any ways to check what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on a debug output in logstash:

```
output {
   stdout {
      codec = rubydebug
   }
}
```

Also, try running your query against Elasticsearch directly (curl) rather than with kibana.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Could you please write an example of the query? I'm very new to ELK...

Comment: Example query would be something like this "curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/*/_search?pretty'" or "curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/filebeat-*/_search?pretty'"

Answer (score -1):

I made an adaptation of the nginx log to the suricata log. I can have the geoip information in the suricata logs. I make the adaptation through swatch and send to a log file configured in filebeat.

Ex:
nginx.access.referrer: ET INFO Session Traversal Utilities for NAT (STUN Binding Request) [**

nginx.access.geoip.location:
{
“lon”: -119.688,
“lat”: 45.8696
}

Use the swatch to read the suricata logs and send them to the shell script that will do the adaptation.

Ex:
echo "$IP - - [$nd4] \"GET $IP2:$PORT2 --- $TYPE HTTP/1.1\" 777 0 \"$CVE\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (NONE) (NONE) NONE\"" >> /var/log/suricata_mod.log

Then configure filebeat.yml:

- document_type: nginx-access

  paths:

  - /var/log/suricata_mod.log

Restart filebeat.

Finally configure the logstash:

```
    filter {
         if [type] == "nginx-access" {
       grok {
  match => { "message" => ["%{IPORHOST:[nginx][access][remote_ip]} - %{DATA:[nginx][access][user_name]} \[%{HTTPDATE:[nginx][access][time]}\] \"%{WORD:[nginx][access][method]} %{DATA:[nginx][access][url]} HTTP/%{NUMBER:[$
  remove_field => "message"} 

    mutate {      
    add_field => { "read_timestamp" => "%{@timestamp}" }} 

    date {
    match => [ "[nginx][access][time]", "dd/MMM/YYYY:H:m:s Z" ]
    remove_field => "[nginx][access][time]"}

    useragent {
       source => "[nginx][access][agent]"
       target => "[nginx][access][user_agent]"
       remove_field => "[nginx][access][agent]"} 

    geoip {
       source => "[nginx][access][remote_ip]"
       target => "[nginx][access][geoip]"
       database => "/opt/GeoLite2-City.mmdb"}} }     output {
      elasticsearch {
          hosts => [ "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200" ]
          manage_template => false
          document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
          index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"}}
```

And restart logstash. In Kibana create a filebeat- * index. Ready.